# How to get function names instad of addresses in Visual Studio's CPU profiling?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm making a game using SDL2, and I want to track down bottlenecks in perfomance. In CPU profiling, I can see the CPU usage of my functions, yet all SDL stuff is marked as SDL2.dll!0x000..., which isn't helpful. How to make it display the function names instead of addresses?

Comment: Link with a debug-build of SDL?

Answer (score 1):

You could either:

- assure you have the .pdb files along with the SDL dll files (in the same directory, side by side);
- add an entry to the Symbol Location Diretories list (Options->Debugging->Symbols) that points to a directory containing all the SDL related .pdb files.

Comment: Visual Studio can create PDB files for release builds, too. But interpreting the results does require a bit more work as inlining will be reflected in the PSB as well - there can be functions missing entirely.